# Git push stopped working, giving error "Repository not found"; git pull works ok

Tags: git, github

At some moment `git push` stopped working.

Running from command line (and IDE) gives the following error:

```
F:\...>git push -v --set-upstream origin abc
Pushing to https://github.com/username/reponame
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/reponame/' not found
```

Github client was able to push the branch, so it's not permissions on github side. Git pull from command line works ok, so it's not broken key or something. The repo is private, I wouldn't be let to perform pull/fetch. Tried to clone to other local folder (`git clone` works ok too, btw), didn't help.

```
git version 2.14.3.windows.1
```

I was able to push few hours ago and pretty sure that didn't change anything...

```
>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/username/reponame (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/reponame (push)
```

**Upd.** Tried clonning ssh version of the url `git@github.com:user/reponame.git` - and pushing works absolutely fine! This basically resolves my problem, but still I'm wondering why it used to work like few hours ago and at some moment just stopped.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` tell you?

Comment: @FabienBouleau added to the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me - switching to ssh url: changing in `.git/config`

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/username/reponame
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:username/reponame
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your username + password as well. Normally the credential manager stores these information but in some cirtumstances these information is lost.

Just use the following syntax:

```
git push -v --set-upstream origin abc https://username:passwd@github.com/username/reponame
```

Comment: Seems like something wrong in syntax of the command, + if credentials are missing, why pull works ok (I'm working with private repository)