# remote: Repository not found for git pull

Tags: git, github

When I do `git pull` I get the following error

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/repo.git' not found
```

But when I run `git pull https://username@github.com/repo.git`, git is able to pull the repo and doesn't ask for a password.

Why do I need to mention my username now? 
PS: I did set `git config user.name username`

Part of config file

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"] 
        url = https://github.com/repo.git 
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
[user] 
        name = github_username
```

Comment: Can you share your `.git/config` file?

Comment: [remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
        name = github_username

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: I gues you need `git pull origin`. If this doesn't work: what does `git remote show origin` state?

Comment: It worked with the solution from [Question 47909038](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909038/git-push-stopped-working-giving-error-repository-not-found-git-pull-works-ok)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a *git* username and a github username is the same thing. A *git* user name is an identifier for your commits on the local machine.

Is it possible that the path of the repository is entered incorrectly? For example, you can check by logging into github and looking at the URL under 'Clone or Download'. In most cases it takes the following form

> https://github.com/repository/repo.git

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are trying to pull via http both times? The second path (without the https) seems like ssh authentication to me. 
If you have set ssh, git won't ask you for authentication because the ssh key is your actual authentication.

Comment: Hi Dimitrios, I am using https both times. I do have a ssh key set up. My question is why can't I just do git pull and why do I need to give whole path.

Comment: If this a repo you are working on and you are not just cloning a project  try to use for `git add remote origin repo_path`  to add the repo as a remote and then it will work.